# Booting takes too much time (around2 minutes) on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 19.04, 20.04

I was using Ubuntu 19.04 as a new user. From the very beginning that I had it installed , it seemed to be taking too much time for booting up. Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu2 0.04 , but the issue has not been solved. I looked up several similar questions here ,  and yet I am unable to fine a solution myself.
Please note that I dual boot with windows10 , and Windows seems to take much less time to boot.
I do think that reason is somehow the graphics...

My PC Specifications:
AMD Ryzen 2200G with Integrated Graphics.
16 GB Ram @ 2666Mz
Asus Prime A320M-K Motherboard.
Linux is installed on an HDD , 500GB

Here is the output from systemd-analyze blame

```
tejas@tejas-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo systemd-analyze blame
[sudo] password for tejas:
40.445s plymouth-quit-wait.service                       
25.389s snapd.service                                        
24.305s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
23.674s udisks2.service                                      
15.360s dev-sdb2.device                                      
14.352s accounts-daemon.service                              
14.304s ModemManager.service                                 
10.949s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
10.479s polkit.service                                       
 9.799s avahi-daemon.service                                 
 9.793s NetworkManager.service                               
 9.665s switcheroo-control.service                           
 9.657s wpa_supplicant.service                               
 9.656s thermald.service                                     
 9.653s systemd-logind.service                               
 8.424s dev-loop10.device                                    
 7.294s dev-loop11.device                                    
 7.105s dev-loop8.device                                     
 7.080s dev-loop9.device                                     
 6.908s dev-loop12.device                                    
 6.373s dev-loop13.device                                    
 6.287s dev-loop0.device                                     
 6.203s dev-loop1.device                                     
 5.819s systemd-resolved.service                             
 5.793s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
 5.537s dev-loop4.device                                     
 5.362s dev-loop3.device                                     
 5.101s dev-loop5.device                                     
 5.039s dev-loop2.device                                     
 5.022s rsyslog.service                                      
 4.955s dev-loop6.device                                     
 4.876s dev-loop7.device                                     
 3.754s grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
 3.305s systemd-udevd.service                                
 3.265s gdm.service                                          
 3.227s grub-common.service                                  
 2.779s colord.service                                       
 2.579s fwupd.service                                        
 2.516s apport.service                                       
 2.289s e2scrub_reap.service                                 
 2.220s gpu-manager.service                                  
 2.069s user@1000.service                                    
 1.845s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-75DC\x2d8465.service
 1.689s apparmor.service                                     
 1.327s systemd-modules-load.service                         
 1.257s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
 1.254s systemd-sysusers.service                             
 1.250s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                   
 1.061s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-33.mount               
 1.050s systemd-random-seed.service                          
 1.048s snap-inkscape-7627.mount                             
  990ms snapd.apparmor.service                               
  963ms systemd-sysctl.service                               
  850ms modprobe@drm.service                                 
  791ms swapfile.swap                                        
  752ms systemd-timesyncd.service                            
  739ms kerneloops.service                                   
  700ms keyboard-setup.service                               
  588ms upower.service                                       
  563ms snap-core-9066.mount                                 
  557ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount              
  541ms snap-atom-250.mount                                  
  530ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
  530ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
  529ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
  528ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                             
  526ms systemd-journald.service                             
  525ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
  524ms snap-core-8935.mount                                 
  477ms snapd.seeded.service                                 
  470ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1502.mount              
  426ms snap-core18-1754.mount                               
  423ms snap-julia-13.mount                                  
  418ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-27.mount               
  398ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
  387ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                         
  367ms snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-9.mount                
  345ms ufw.service                                          
  315ms pppd-dns.service                                     
  301ms openvpn.service                                      
  270ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
  256ms snap-eclipse-48.mount                                
  222ms snap-core18-1705.mount                               
  210ms plymouth-start.service                               
  186ms systemd-remount-fs.service                           
  179ms console-setup.service                                
  178ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount              
  169ms boot-efi.mount                                       
  162ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                       
  116ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
  113ms setvtrgb.service                                     
  104ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                        
   61ms plymouth-read-write.service                          
   12ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
   11ms alsa-restore.service                                 
    4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
    3ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
    1ms snapd.socket                                         
  371us clean-mount-point@media-tejas-USB.service
```

Here is the  output from systemd-analyze critical chain

```
tejas@tejas-System-Product-Name:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 27.584s
└─multi-user.target @1min 27.583s
  └─kerneloops.service @59.503s +175ms
    └─network-online.target @59.441s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @44.400s +15.039s
        └─NetworkManager.service @27.374s +17.024s
          └─dbus.service @27.371s
            └─basic.target @27.133s
              └─sockets.target @27.133s
                └─snapd.socket @27.132s +896us
                  └─sysinit.target @26.807s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @25.934s +872ms
                      └─apparmor.service @24.152s +1.781s
                        └─local-fs.target @24.151s
                          └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @1min 14.724s
                            └─run-user-1000.mount @1min 3.167s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @8.897s
                                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @8.008s +8>
                                  └─systemd-sysusers.service @6.679s +1.328s
                                    └─systemd-remount-fs.service @6.303s +198ms
                                      └─systemd-journald.socket @6.026s
                                        └─system.slice @5.946s
                                          └─-.slice @5.947s
```

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Don't have a solution since almost everything seems to be taking too long.  Do you have a lot of data on drive or have backups?  It just might be easier to do a clean install.  With Windows should do a check for bios updates and do a good hardware check do see if cause by something else than OS problem.

Comment: No. I don't have much data . Drive has been in use only since a couple of months. I had once installed 19.04 , It was just as slow . Later , due to an error , I had to clean install 19.04 again. Even after doing that , the booting took almost the same amount of time. I hoped that updating the system would fix it , and so did I update to 20.04 , and yet its absolutely unchanged. I will make it a point to check for bios updates. Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: Please add `systemd-analyze critical-chain` to your question above.

Comment: as suggested by crip659 , I have tried updating bios. Yet no help.

Comment: Have added systemd-analyze critical chain